# Automatically pass data from JavaScript to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

My program consists of two parts:

1)run.php generates and shares token via JS which is needed for my php functions.

```
$('.setURL').attr('href', 'save.php?token='+text);
<a class="setURL"><button>Save Settings</button></a>
```

2)code2.php receives token from code.php via $_GET and launches the functions.

```
$token = $_GET['token'];
```

For scaling i need to launch this process automatically through cron and looking for a way to share token from run.php to save.php automatically without submitting forms or clicking buttons.

Honestly i tried to investigate but didn't find a way or clues of how to do it.

Comment: I dont know what you are trying to do, but this definitely is not the correct solution. Why not have PHP generate a token and store it in a database?

Comment: There is big logic involved but shortly saying it is not possible to generate this token via PHP.

Comment: Your original post says "1)run.php generates and shares token"

So is PHP generating the token or not?

Comment: It generates token via JS, to save it i must pass the data to new php file and  capture it via get

Comment: You’re not making much sense here; trying to trigger _client-side_ JavaScript functionality via cron is rather nonsense. The cron executes a script on the _server_ - so you would have to not only make an HTTP request or start a script there with cron, but an actual headless browser or something else that can execute JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

> I really **don't** understand, What you want to do actually, But the **Answer** for your **question** is,

Without clicking button, programmatically use can do it using `ajax calls`.

**Vanilla Script**

```html
<script>
  //ignores response
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.open("GET", "save.php?token="+text, true);
  xhttp.send();
</script>
```

**jQuery**

```html
<script>
  $.get( "save.php?token="+text ); //ignores response
</script>
```

**If you need to open as a page**

```html
<script>
  window.open("save.php?token="+text, "_self"); //load in same tab
</script>
```